# What is way to give highest priority to normal function over mutex based single thread in main program?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I have implemented ticketing based one program. Now whenever ticket issued at that time i am sending that ticket data to ticket db . i am storing  ticketing data from ticket db to config db at every 5 minute using thread and mutex.

where one thread I need to give Highest priority to normal function first where new ticket get generated.

So Guide me **How to give highest priority to Ticket creation function over mutex based single thread  in main program ?**

Sample example of my implemented code:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
    
    void int_handler_on_create_ticket_key_press ()
    {
    // logic of create ticket
    // Store generated ticket no in ticket db
    }
    
    int main()
    {

    // create thread using pthread_create which store ticket related details //from ticket db to config db. and send ticket related details to server db //a every 5 minute 
    }
    
    void thread_fun ()
    {
    //pythread_mutex_lock();
    //logic of store ticket related details from ticket db to config db. and send ticket related details to server db
    //pythread_mutex_unlock();
    }
```

Note:
when ticket get created at that time sending and storing data using thread does not get to stop and as well as allow ticket creation

Comment: This description makes a little sense. Post your code (not the whole code, but a demonstrating example)

Comment: There are numerous existing answers addressing pthreads priority.  This question is likely a dupe of some of them, but its English is too garbled for me to be sure which.